# Permissions per folder in samba share

Tags: samba, network-attached-storage, cifs

I need to create a public share where there is a folder *public* and folder *user* such as everyone (including guests) have full access to *public* and for *user* only the specific user has full access but everyone else have Read and Execute permissions.

this is my share configuration.

```
[public]
  comment = public storage
  path = /home/shares/public
  read only = no
  guest ok = yes
  browsable = yes
```

I have also tried

```
[public]
  comment = public storage
  path = /home/shares/public
  guest account = samba-guest
  read only = yes
  guest ok = yes
  guest only = yes
  write list = user
  browsable = yes
```

I have already asked this question on SuperUser but I did not get an answer.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing? What are the permissions on `/home/shares/public`? What are the settings for "map to guest", "guest account"?

Comment: @Thomas The permissions are read only and rw for user. map to guest is bad user and guest account is samba-user.